# CleanSwift - Can a presenter directly call router function?

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, clean-architecture

I am working on CleanSwift architecture. I see there is no direct communication between a presenter and associated scenes router in diagram,

[image]

But often there are certain scenarios where a presenter only needs to rout to another view controller. I wonder if its permitted for presenter to call a router routeToOtherView() function directly, rather calling an extra function in view controller which simply redirect.

Comment: This usually breaks data flow, because sometimes you need to pass some data to segue from controller and presenter cannot request data from UI

Comment: Thanks @tereks, but what if there is no data, can we use two method in router, one for data one for no data. when no data, we call from presenter, when need data we call via controller. ?? whats your suggestion?

Comment: IMHO there is no much difference where router is stored and called, we have VIPER with presenter holding router, so why you cannot use some of VIPER in your code. More important is keeping the same architecture for the whole project and personal gain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have also used **CleanSwift** in couple of projects. What I liked about this architecture is that it works in **unidirectional** flow. And in this flow **ViewController** works with **Router**, **Interactor** and **Presenter**. **Unidirectional** flow allows us to find bugs easily.

Let's take one scenario to understand this. Suppose you have a Button and click on that you want to move from **ViewController1** to **ViewController2**. By any mistake you write **ViewController3** instead of **ViewController2**, now it's showing **ViewController3** on Button click. To solve this bug you have to look at routing mechanism. And you know that routing mechanism resides in the **ViewController1**, so to solve it you should just move on to **ViewController1** and find the responsible function for route and solve the bug.

You are breaking the flow, if you move routing in **Presenter** for some of the cases when there is only need is to move from one **Controller** to another. Also the architecture will be dependant on you because you have to keep in mind that whether you have added routing mechanism in **Presenter** or in **Controller**. It also affects the collaborative environment, where your counter part has to search for the routing mechanism. It will also take time to solve the bug if you observe the above Scenario.

So it's better idea to don't break the flow. It's good to spend more to make it precious. Hope this answer can help.

Comment: My Pleasure @sazzad